# Is there any connector for SMD components

Tags: capacitor, pcb, soldering, surface-mount

I want to fine-tune the resonance of multiple LC-circuits with hand made inductors(coils), and SMD capacitors (NP0 type). Currently, I am tuning the resonance frequency by soldering and desoldering capacitors until I get the required accuracy. But soldering and desoldering is quite inconvenient and also, it may harm my PCB.

**My question is: do we have any connectors/sockets to hold SMA components (e.g sizes 0806, 1206) in a PCB so that swapping the components become easier?**

Other related details about the application:
This will be used in high-Q resonance circuit at 5-10MHz. Therefore, the contact resistance is expected to be as small as possible. Current through the capacitors will be less than 5A at 5-10MHz.

Comment: What range of capacitance do you need to cover your tuning requirements?

Comment: @Andyaka, Capacitance range would be from few pF to hundreds of pF (e.g from 1.5pF up to 600pF)

Comment: If you have frequent desoldering/soldering cycles you should use ENIG PCBs for testing purposes and cheaper PCB for production.

Comment: invest in smd tweezers. tahs what they were made for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use SMD fuse sockets[SMD fuse socket](https://www.google.com/search?q=SMD%20Fuse%20socket&rlz=1C1CHZL_enCA707CA707&sxsrf=ACYBGNTD2T5mjqHB_sBqh_jjb5SwAf4Xhw:1580987557678&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=AGZoBCNXpdfv4M%253A%252Cyu02koaBJrldRM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRfSuAiKpLlS3lfDlnDWZ7dSiOjlg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjm7ZPO5bznAhVtmuAKHd3RB0MQ9QEwAHoECAoQHA#imgrc=AGZoBCNXpdfv4M:), adapter PCB or [anisotropic test socket](https://docplayer.net/21485025-Burn-in-test-socket-workshop.html) . Take into account that there will be higher parasitic inductance for such solutions

Comment: Thanks, This is interesting - will have to check how much is the effect of parasitics. I am now trying to look for any good models suitable for high-frequency usage with low parasitics.

Answer (score 6):

I understand your inconvenience but SMD components are made to be soldered. I use for that kind of job a desolder tweezer like this one https://www.weller-tools.com/professional/EUR/en/Professional/Soldering+technology/Soldering+irons/Desoldering+tweezers/WTA+50++ and it is quite easy to swap SMD devices

Comment: Thanks, I am currently using one. But my PCB is a self made, so multiple desoldering damages the pad. But it seems that this is the only option.

Comment: @Pojj How is it damaging the pad? are your tips too small and your tweezers too hot? are you applying flux before desoldering? or maybe dozens and dozens of times is just to much for a pad. how many times are you talking about?